# chrome.browserAction.setIcon() not work with content_security_policy

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, content-security-policy

I have added functionality to my Chrome extension such that the icon button changes color when it is clicked. The code is simple:

```
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"icon_pink_lines.png", tabId:tab.id});
```

However, this took me a while to figure out because it turns out that it doesn't work when the content_security_policy is set in manifest.json. I originally had

```
 "content_security_policy": "default-src 'none'; script-src 'self'"
```

The question is, what, if anything, do I lose by removing this? Or should it just be something else to work with the icon change? To be honest, I just copied the original policy from some sample manifest file and haven't thought about it since.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [default value](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html#restrictions) for `content_security_policy` if you don't set it up yourself:

`script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'`

Yours is tighter though. It does not allow to load any external resources (while default policy does not allow only external scripts). It seems that your `icon_pink_linkes.png` is treated as an external resource and blocked by CSP. This looks like a bug to me, you can report it [here](http://crbug.com) (I've searched for similar bugs, but haven't found any).

Comment: `default-src 'none'` would sets a default source list for `img-src`. Since `img-src` isn't specified, it falls back to that default source list, which says "Nothing is allowed, muwahaha." To allow images, you can either allow `'self'` as a default source (e.g. `default-src 'self'`), or add `img-src 'self'` to your policy.